# SQL Table valued parameters from C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

Just a few years behind, but I discovered table valued parameters for stored procedures/UDFs today.  They are the ideal solution to a problem I'm having, but I can't get them to work from C#.

I have a UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSurveyScores
    @Survey     bigint, 
    @Question   nvarchar(max),
    @Area       StringList      READONLY,
    @JobCode    StringList      READONLY
AS BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM SurveyResults WHERE RespondentArea IN (Select val from @Area) AND RespondentJobCode IN (select val from @JobCodes)
END
```

(StringList is the type I created, it's just a table valued type with a single column called val, defined as nvarchar(256))

Then from SQL Server Management Studio, I can do this:

```
declare @area StringList;
insert into @area(val) values('NW'),('NE'),('SW');
// Get all survey respondent job codes from the SurveyRespondent table.
declare @jobcodes StringList;
insert into @jobcodes select distinct jobcode from dbo.SurveyRespondent;

select * from dbo.GetSurveyScores(3, 'Q3', @area, @jobcodes)
```

That works brilliantly.

From C#, I get no results (no exceptions), using this code: (I'm using DataTables because the actual code I intend to drop this into uses DataTables already)

```
DataTable areas = new DataTable("StringList");
areas.Columns.Add("val");
areas.Rows.Add("NW"); areas .Rows.Add("NE"); areas .Rows.Add("SW");

DataTable jobcodes = new DataTable("StringList");
jobcodes.Columns.Add("val");
jobcodes.Rows.Add("JC1"); jobcodes .Rows.Add("JC2");    

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.GetSurveyScores(3, 'Q3', @area, @jc)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", areas);
cmd.Parameters["@area"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
cmd.Parameters["@area"].TypeName = "StringList";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jc", jobcodes);
cmd.Parameters["@jc"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
cmd.Parameters["@jc"].TypeName = "StringList";

DataTable results = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {

    da.Fill(results);

}

Console.WriteLine(results.Rows.Count);
```

The final line prints 0.  I'm sure I must be missing something simple, but after 6 hours of trying, I think I need a new set of eyes to look at it.

Comment: `WHERE RespondentArea IN (@Area)` should surely be `WHERE RespondentArea IN (SELECT val FROM @Area)`?

Comment: Yep, missed that bit. That is how it is.  Corrected now.

Comment: For jobcodes and areas data tables, you are adding row values in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Sorry guys, jumping between C# and Javascript caused the single quotes, and looking at this for so long/trying remove sensitive data caused another few mistakes.  Should all make sense now, I hope...

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL profiler to see what query its passing to the database?

Comment: Sadly this system is SQL 2008 Express, which doesn't seem to come with the profiler (please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: Have you tried using the value returned from `AddWithValue` and not the lookup in the table?  Should be no difference, but worth a shot.

Comment: Only a comment.  Declare the CommandType and ParameterDirection.  And try a public class the implements IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> rather than a DataTable as then at lest you can debug the class to see if it is pulling the values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is that you are not returning anything from your function, although to be honest I'm not sure how it was able to run in MGT studio because it looks like a syntax error. The function should look something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSurveyScores (
    @Survey     bigint, 
    @Question   nvarchar(max),
    @Area       StringList      READONLY,
    @JobCodes    StringList      READONLY )
RETURNS @Results TABLE  (RespondentArea NVARCHAR(256), RespondentJobCode NVARCHAR(256))
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT @Results
    SELECT * FROM SurveyResults WHERE RespondentArea IN (Select val from @Area) AND RespondentJobCode IN (select val from @JobCodes)
    RETURN
END
go
```

Id' image that the syntax you actually used was slightly different, and the select statement is getting executed but the return value of the function has no results.